# textoverflow inside custom list tile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView and I want to display the items in my custom list tile, the problem is that my text oveflow the tile, i want to add TextOverflow.ellipsis but it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: songss.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Song song = songss[index];
              
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor))),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("${index + 1}",
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
                              SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    song.title,
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, //Here i want to handle overflow
                                  ),
                                  Text(_getSongDuration(song.duration),
                                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                ),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) =>
                                      null,
                                  child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
```

I tried using expanded and flex but it gives me error.
Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you tell me, where it is overflowing? I mean is it overflowing horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actualy managed to solve the problem.

```
return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: songss.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Song song = songss[index];

          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor))),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("${index + 1}",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
                  SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          song.title,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        Text(_getSongDuration(song.duration),
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => null,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => null,
                    child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

I've just rewrote the whole list, removing one or two rows.
So i'm gonna answer the question, thank you for your help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Give `height`,`width` to the Parent Widget of `Text` widget and then wrap `Text` with Expanded

Your error will be solved as expanded/flex need some max parent size to take space from.